# How to fix "Change MdiParent in MdiChild" in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

My codes to change MdiChild in MdiParent class

```
        public void SetupMdi(Form form)
        {
            clearMdi();
            activeMdiForms.Add(form);
            form.MdiParent = this;
            form.Show();
            form.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            foreach(Form forms in activeMdiForms)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(forms.ToString());
            }
            return;
        }

        public void clearMdi()
        {
            foreach(Form form in activeMdiForms)
            {
                form.Dispose();
            }
            activeMdiForms.Clear();
            return;
        }
```

It's working perfectly in parent class

```
        private void Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VersionChecker ver = new VersionChecker();
            versionLbl.Text = "Depo Stok Programı Version " + earlySettings.version;
            SetupMdi(new Login());
            GCTimer.Start();
        }
```

But I called SetupMdi method from child form its working but child form not showing but it using ram

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
     public async void login()
    {
        earlySettings.usrName = obj.UserName;
        MainMenu form = new MainMenu();
        new Menu().SetupMdi(new MainMenuMdi());
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried an ApiClass its not working like child class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I called SetupMdi method from child form its working but child
>   form not showing but it using ram

Assuming your code is in an actual MdiChild, then you can cast the [MdiParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to your parent type (I believe, `Menu`?), and then call the `SetupMdi()` method:

```
// ... assuming we are in an MdiChild ...
((Menu)this.MdiParent).SetupMdi(new MainMenuMdi());
```